# unable to view http traffic when calling DefaultHttpClient in a Spring controller

Tags: http, traffic

I have a Spring MVC controller that makes a json RESTful webservice call using apache DefaultHttpClient.  I wanted to view the http request/response data of that webservice call, I've tried firebug, wireshark, fiddler, but had no success.

they do show the traffic when I'm using a browser.

below is the jist of the webservice call

```
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8888");  // set proxy to fiddler 
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(targetUrl);
     // sample targetUrl = "http://localhost:9080/SampleBackend/sample-backend-json.jsp"
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}");
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);

            HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run the packet capture (tcpdump most likely) on the loopback interface of the server. You can then download the captured data and view it in wireshark, same as a live capture.